# how to undo tar operation?

Tags: unix, freebsd, tar, undo

I used **tar -cvf sample_directory/*** and didn't specify file.tar.gz.  So the Makefile within the folder is in some unreadable format. is there a way to recover my Makefile?

Comment: Btw, this belongs on superuser, I think.

Comment: Recover it from your version control system, because you are using one, right?

Answer (score 6):

The Makefile within the folder contains the output from the `tar` command, so it's not "some unreadable format", it's gzipped tar format. that tar archive won't contain your missing Makefile though.

The comments about recovering the Makefile from your backups or from your version control system are apt. This is in fact what you need to do.

If you don't have a backup or the Makefile wasn't checked in to a version control system, then there isn't a feasible way to recover its contents.

Aside from the issue of your poor lost Makefile, a piece of advice about using `tar`: never tar up a bunch of individual files inside a directory. Always tar up the directory itself instead. There is not much more annoying than untarring an archive that contains a big bunch or files instead of a single directory (which then contains files). Doing that makes a mess by littering files all over the directory that happens to be the current directory. Please be nice to whoever is going to extract your tar files (which might be yourself, later on!), follow convention, and tar up complete directories.

```
tar -czf file.tar.gz sample_directory
```

As a bonus, if you do it that way, and you forget the output filename like this:

```
tar -czf sample_directory
```

You won't squash anything, you'll just get an error.